# Saving ManagementObject query as double

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm currently making a program the monitors the uptime and size of servers on a network. I've run into some problems with displaying the size of the servers and what space is left.

My code is

```
public void setSpace(string ip)
{
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + ip + "\\root\\cimv2");
    scope.Connect();

    ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
    SelectQuery query1 = new SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk");

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query1);
    ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection1 = searcher1.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
    {
        // Display the remote computer information
        Console.WriteLine("Computer Name : {0}",
            m["csname"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Windows Directory : {0}",
            m["WindowsDirectory"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Operating System: {0}",
            m["Caption"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", m["Version"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer : {0}", m["Manufacturer"]);
        Console.WriteLine();

    }

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Disk Name : {0}", mo["Name"]);
        Console.WriteLine("   Disk Size : {0}", mo["Size"]);
        Console.WriteLine("  FreeSpace : {0}", mo["FreeSpace"]);
        Console.WriteLine("  Disk DeviceID : {0}", mo["DeviceID"]);
        Console.WriteLine("  Disk VolumeName : {0}", mo["VolumeName"]);
        Console.WriteLine("  Disk SystemName : {0}", mo["SystemName"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Disk VolumeSerialNumber : {0}", mo["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
        Console.WriteLine();

        freeSpace = freeSpace + (double)mo["FreeSpace"];
        totalSpace = totalSpace + (double)mo["Size"];

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm trying to take the FreeSpace and Size numbers and put them in a double variable.

```
freeSpace = freeSpace + (double)mo["FreeSpace"];
totalSpace = totalSpace + (double)mo["Size"];
```

When I try to run the program I get an exception.

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a NullReferenceException because the code doesn't return a specified member (eg. FreeSpace). I tried the code in my PC where I have 2 partitions and 1 DVD drive. Exception was raised when it reached the DVD drive (empty disk) while it was iterating the queryCollection1 object. So you must check if the member of mo object you want is a null reference.

```
if (mo["FreeSpace"] != null)
    freeSpace = freeSpace + (ulong)mo["FreeSpace"];

if (mo["Size"] != null)
    totalSpace = totalSpace + (ulong)mo["Size"];
```

I also change the cast to ulong because FreeSpace and Size are ulong type. And there's an implicit conversion from ulong to double. You don't need to change the variable type of freeSpace and totalSpace.

Answer (score -1):

Your casts are wrong. Instead of cast to double, you should cast to ulong. The variables freeSpace and totalSpace should be of the same type and initialized before the first use.

```
freeSpace = freeSpace + (ulong)mo["FreeSpace"];
totalSpace = totalSpace + (ulong)mo["Size"];
```

Comment: Why a downvote? I've tested my answer and it's working. Test was made with ip=localhost and local variables for freeSpace and totalSpace.